# Unicode character best suited for being upside-down small L, with widest font compatibility?

Tags: unicode, fonts, web

I want a character that's nearly a vertical line and extends significantly *below* the baseline, and that's supported by (at least one of) the fonts installed by default on popular operating systems. I could use 'l' or '1' or '|', but it looks bad when all the other upside-down characters extend downwards, and this is the only one pointing up. I'd use @font-face (it's for a webpage), but it also shows up in tooltips and page titles so that's not good enough.

The ideal would of course be [Latin Small Letter Turned L](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a781/index.htm), but the [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a781/fontsupport.htm) is awful. [Latin Small Letter Dotless J](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/237/index.htm) would also be acceptable, and the [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/237/fontsupport.htm) is not quite as bad, but I still don't see any of the default Windows fonts in the list.

What's my least-bad option?

(A fair suggestion would be, "Why do you need this? Maybe there are other solutions" -- and I'll figure out a plan B if I have to, but first I'd like to know if I have to. I also recognize that this is a niche question. If this is not the right place to ask it, where is?)

Comment: Try [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/).

Comment: That's an amazing tool. Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I was able to find is TURNED GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA (U+2129) “℩”, which is present in Arial Unicode MS and Lucida Sans Unicode. The main problem with it is its small size—its height is just the x-height, roughly speaking.

Or maybe THAI CHARACTER LAKKHANGYAO (U+0E45) “ๅ”? Arial Unicode MS and MS Sans Serif.

(I suppose this is for an improved [upside-down converter](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm). Such converters can be fun, but they often suffer from the effects of mixing fonts.)

Comment: Lakkhangyao seems to have potential, thanks. (Oddly enough I have no clue which font on my Linux system is being used to display it, as DejaVu for once isn't listed as supporting it...)

Comment: Lakkhangyao ended up being the lucky winner.